# CoRegisterClassObject CO_E_WRONG_SERVER_IDENTITY (0x80004015)

Tags: c#, .net-core, com

I am building a out-of-process COM server in .NET 5 using [this COM registration class](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/OutOfProcCOM/COMRegistration).

The client is a service running as system which I do not control.

With the server set with `RunAs = Interactive User` (default value in my case) everything works as expected during debugging: the server can register and the client can call the server as an out-of-process COM server.

However in my case the server runs as system (not as a service though) when there is no user logged in. Which of course means that the registration fails when `RunAs = Interactive User` with error `CO_E_WRONG_SERVER_IDENTITY (0x80004015)`.

I've tried to fix it by setting `RunAs` to `Launching User` (by deleting the `RunAs` value from the registry) and while that allows my process running as system to register successfully, the client cannot seem to connect to the existing COM server and instead it works as an in-process COM server where the COM client creates a new process with the COM server.

I've also tried setting `RunAs = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and looking at permissions but in both cases I had the same issue as before.

So how can I register an out-of-process COM server to run as SYSTEM - without being a service - while allowing a COM client that is a service running as SYSTEM to connect to it?

Comment: Do you have any reproducing sample project?

Comment: @SimonMourier Unfortunately not. I've send you a friend request on LinkedIn just now if you want to discuss it more in detail.

Comment: The service has to run with a user account that the server acknowledges.  So you have to start the service with "RunAs".   Another choice is to allow the service to accept a GUEST Privileges.  A connection where an account cannot be verified defaults to GUEST.

Comment: @jdweng How would you setup the server to acknowledge certain user accounts? As I said, both the server and client run as system (one being a service the other not). Also how would you set it up to allow guest privileges?

Comment: You have to set the Role correctly at the server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true